# Why isn't Django update working on the production server?

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I updated the code for Django version 1.11, but in the server (on azure), Django version 1.9 was installed. so while running the application Django 1.11 function throws an error, says 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'union', which is a Django 1.11 function.

I Installed django 1.11 in virtualenv, but the changes are not reflected in code, while searching for a solution found some answers which says to restart the `uwsgi` and `appache2`(not for) service, restarted `uwsgi` and `nginx` for my case, still no change, and installed Django 1.11 in outside the virtualenv, thats too not accepting..
below line is written in crontab for running the application...

```
/usr/local/bin/lockrun --lockfile /tmp/np_prod.lock 
   -- uwsgi 
      --close-on-exec 
      -s /tmp/uwsgi_np_prod.sock
      --chdir /var/www/html/nextpulse/NextPulse/backend/backend/
      --pp ..
      -w backend.wsgi_prod
      -C666
      -p 32
      -H /var/www/html/nextpulse/NextPulse/backend/venv/
      1>> /tmp/np_log_prod 2>> /tmp/np_err_prod
```

Comment: Have you looked at the start script for the wsgi - is PYTHONPATH set right there?

Comment: @ger.s.brett it's working fine under django 1.9, so there won't be any problem with PYTHONPATH.

Comment: But that was in a different folder. You need to let lhe start script know what django path it should use.

Comment: @ger.s.brett the same virtualenv is used to install the django 1.11, but it accepting django 1.9 only. Still the virtualenv contains the django 1.11 but it running in django 1.9 version

Comment: what do you mean by "accepting django 1.9 only"

Comment: Usually if you install a django installation over another one the lalter one is gone for good. So my suspicion would be that there is a 1.9 installation somewhere else and this is the one it is using due to the PYTHONPATH setting.

Comment: @ger.s.brett "accepting django 1.9 only", means it runs on django version 1.9, and not migrating to django 1.11

Comment: I do had the suspicion that there is a 1.9 installation some where else, so I installed 1.11 else where I found, still I don't know where is that particular installation is...

Comment: That is why you should look for the start script for your wsgi server. How did you restart it?

Comment: @ger.s.brett if we delete the socket, will it again created???